# Featch data to tableview

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, segue, cell

In my first vc (ViewController) I have button with action `performSegue`. In override func `prepare(for segue:)` I want to send data to another view controller.

This is my code:

```
if segue.identifier == "nextVC" {
        let data1 = ["TITLE", "TITLE2"]
        let data2 = ["DESCRIPTION", "DESCRIPTION 2", "DESCRIPTION 3"]
        let destination = segue.destination as! DestinationController
        destination.cellString1 = data1
        destination.cellString2 = data2
        destination.array = array
```

In my second vc (DestinationController) I have variable `cellString1`, `cellString2` and `array` like below:

```
var array: [String] = []
var cellString1: [String] = []
var cellString2: [String] = []
```

In array I send to second vc id of tableView cell in first vc like below:

```
["0", "1", "1", "0", "1"]
```

In second vc I have tableView too with code (in tableview(cellForRowAt:))like below:

```
if array[indexPath.row] == "0" {
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellString1[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return cell
    } else if array[indexPath.row] == "1" {
        cell2.textLabel?.text = cellString2[indexPath.row]
        cell2.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        cell2.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell2
```

where I want to detect if array in cell have value (0 or 1) then label of cell take value from `cellString1` or `cellString2` and show text of this label. When I delete cells textLabel configuration, colors of cells background are correct (`black, red, red, black, red)` however in full code I have error `(Index out of range)` in line `cell.textLabel?.text = cellString1[indexPath.row]`.
Is possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This should be :

```
    destination.cellString1 = data1
    destination.cellString2 = data2
    destination.array = array
    let destination = segue.destination as! DestinationController
```

you should perform segue after `destination.cellString1 = data1`, `destination.cellString2 = data2` and `destination.array = array`. Else these properties won't be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 titles, 3 descriptions and 5 color flags. If you are using multiple arrays as data source you have to make sure that the number of items are always the same.

For example if you return `array.count` in `numberOfRows` then `cellForRow` is called 5 times. But there is no item at `indexPath.row > 1` in `cellString1` and `indexPath.row > 2` in `cellString2`. This causes the out-of-range exception.

**Basically you are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. Don't do that.**

Use a custom struct instead and rather than "0" and "1" strings use a `Bool`

```
struct Item {
   var title : String
   var description : String
   var colorFlag : Bool
}
```

Then create `Item` instances with the appropriate data and pass **one** array.

Comment: I'm try fix my problem as you write but still not working. Can I send you somewhere my whole code to check?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because the 3 arrays have different count , and sure indexPath will exceed for `cellString1` as it contains 2 items , and second "0" of array is in index 3 which exceeds count of `cellString1`